# Python NamedTemporaryFile - ValueError When Reading

Tags: python, temporary-files, tftp, hashlib

I am having an issue writing to a NamedTemporaryFile in Python and then reading it back.  The function downloads a file via tftpy to the temp file, reads it, hashes the contents, and then compares the hash digest to the original file.  The function in question is below:

```
def verify_upload(self, image, destination):
    # create a tftp client
    client = TftpClient(ip, 69, localip=self.binding_ip)
    # generate a temp file to hold the download info
    if not os.path.exists("temp"):
        os.makedirs("temp")
    with NamedTemporaryFile(dir="temp") as tempfile, open(image, 'r') as original:
        try:
            # attempt to download the target image
            client.download(destination, tempfile, timeout=self.download_timeout)
        except TftpTimeout:
            raise RuntimeError("Could not download {0} from {1} for verification".format(destination, self.target_ip))
        # hash the original file and the downloaded version
        original_digest = hashlib.sha256(original.read()).hexdigest()
        uploaded_digest = hashlib.sha256(tempfile.read()).hexdigest()
        if self.verbose:
            print "Original SHA-256: {0}\nUploaded SHA-256: {1}".format(original_digest, uploaded_digest)
        # return the hash comparison
        return original_digest == uploaded_digest
```

The problem is that every time I try to execute the line `uploaded_digest = hashlib.sha256(tempfile.read()).hexdigest()` the application errors out with a `ValueError - I/O Operation on a closed file`.  Since the `with` block is not complete I am struggling to understand why the temp file would be closed.  The only possibility I can think of is that tftpy is closing the file after doing the download, but I cannot find any point in the tftpy source where this would be happening.  Note, I have also tried inserting the  line `tempfile.seek(0)` in order to put the file back in a proper state for reading, however this also gives me the `ValueError`.

Is tftpy closing the file possibly?  I read that there is possibly a bug in NamedTemporaryFile causing this problem? Why is the file closed before the reference defined by the `with` block goes out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFTPy is closing the file. When you were looking at the source, you missed the following code path:

```
class TftpClient(TftpSession):
    ...
    def download(self, filename, output, packethook=None, timeout=SOCK_TIMEOUT):
        ...
        self.context = TftpContextClientDownload(self.host,
                                                 self.iport,
                                                 filename,
                                                 output,
                                                 self.options,
                                                 packethook,
                                                 timeout,
                                                 localip = self.localip)
        self.context.start()
        # Download happens here
        self.context.end()  # <--
```

[`TftpClient.download`](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy/blob/master/tftpy/TftpClient.py#L30) calls [`TftpContextClientDownload.end`](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy/blob/master/tftpy/TftpContexts.py#L393):

```
class TftpContextClientDownload(TftpContext):
    ...
    def end(self):
        """Finish up the context."""
        TftpContext.end(self)  # <--
        self.metrics.end_time = time.time()
        log.debug("Set metrics.end_time to %s", self.metrics.end_time)
        self.metrics.compute()
```

[`TftpContextClientDownload.end`](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy/blob/master/tftpy/TftpContexts.py#L393) calls [`TftpContext.end`](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy/blob/master/tftpy/TftpContexts.py#L123):

```
class TftpContext(object):
    ...
    def end(self):
        """Perform session cleanup, since the end method should always be
        called explicitely by the calling code, this works better than the
        destructor."""
        log.debug("in TftpContext.end")
        self.sock.close()
        if self.fileobj is not None and not self.fileobj.closed:
            log.debug("self.fileobj is open - closing")
            self.fileobj.close()  # <--
```

and [`TftpContext.end`](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy/blob/master/tftpy/TftpContexts.py#L123) closes the file.

Comment: Agh!  Of course you're right.  Can I re-open the tempfile after this occurs?

Comment: @Kin3TiX: Normally, the file would be deleted as soon as it's closed, but you can pass `delete=False` to the `NamedTemporaryFile` constructor to prevent that, and then reopen the file by its name afterwards. If you do this, remember that you will be responsible for deleting the file when you're done with it.